# What is happening when you perform build & run on xcode? Can a user (non-dev) reproduce this?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compilation

What is happening when a version of your application exists on an iOS device and you decide to build & run onto the same device? Is this the same as when a person updates their app?

Big reason I'm asking is because my app misbehaves a bit when I build & run our app onto a development device which already has the app on there. However, without the build & run, I can't reproduce the bad behaviour. So I'm wondering if any users will be able to experience this unexpected behaviour through user (non-dev) triggered actions...like building & running.

Comment: The internals of the app (binary, codesign, and usually resources) are replaced, refreshed, then sent a run message from the mobile LaunchD.  Anything else?

Comment: So what exactly is the behavior you are seeing while doing build and run. Normally it should just work fine.

Comment: Is anything in the app's cache / memory retained when it is rebuilt/rerun?